# Prove for any normed space finite dimensional is a Banach Space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Prove for any normed space finite dimensional is a Banach space.

I know the definition of Banach space is a normed space $X$ is complete, i.e., if every Cauchy sequence is convergent.

Let $X$ be normed space, with $\dim(X)=n$. Let $\{x_m\}_{m\in \mathbb N}$ be Cauchy sequence of $X$. How to prove $\{x_m\}_{m\in \mathbb N}$ is convergent? How to connect between finite dimensional with Cauchy sequence? Any hint to prove this problem?

I have read the answer [A finite dimensional normed vector space is a Banach Space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596975/a-finite-dimensional-normed-vector-space-is-a-banach-space), but the proof is not use Cauchy sequence and I confused.

Comment: Which part is confusing to you?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596975/a-finite-dimensional-normed-vector-space-is-a-banach-space It is right we not need to prove Cauchy sequence of X is convergent?

Comment: If you have two equivalent norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$, in the sense that there exist constants $c, C > 0$ such that $$c \|x\|_1 \leq \|x\|_2 \leq C\|x\|_1, \qquad \forall x \in X,$$ then a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is Cauchy w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_1$ if and only if it is Cauchy w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_2$. Next, in the link, it is shown that any two norms on a finite-dimensional space $X$ are equivalent. Then, since we already know a norm that makes $X$ complete (such as the Euclidean norm), we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to show this when you consider the field of real numbers and this for all norms.

Consider $E$ a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and a basis $(e_1, ..., e_n)$ of $E$. It means that for all $x\in E$ you have $x = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}e_i $ where the $x_i$ are real numbers.

Now we need to endow E with a norm, first recall that all norms are **equivalents** in a finite dimensional normed space it will be usefull at some points.

The norm we will consider is $\lVert x\rVert_{\infty} = max_{1\leq i\leq n}\lvert x_i\rvert $. Thus $(E,\lVert\rVert_{\infty})$ is a finite dimensional normed space.

Now consider a Cauchy sequence in $E$, namely $(x^{p})_{p\in\mathbb{N}}$, it means that

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N} : n,m\geq N\implies\lvert x_i^{n} -x_i^{m}\rvert\leq\lVert x^{n} - x^{m}\rVert_{\infty} = max_{1\leq i \leq n}\lvert x_{i}^{n} - x_{i}^{m}\rvert\leq\epsilon$

However for $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ we have that $(x_i^{p})$ is a sequence of real numbers and we have shown that it is Cauchy !

Thus for all $i\in\{1,..n\}$ there exists $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N_{i}\in\mathbb{N} : p\geq N_i\implies \lvert x_i^{p} -x_i\rvert\leq\epsilon$ (since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete)

Now, a candidate we should consider as a limit of $(x^p)_{p\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the vector whose coordinate corresponds to the $x_i$'s that is $x = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ie_i$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and $N = max_{1\leq i\leq n}(N_i)$, then we have that
$p\geq N\implies max_{1\leq i\leq n}\lvert x_i^p - x_i\rvert = \lVert x^p - x\rVert_{\infty}\leq\epsilon$ which shows the convergence of $(x^p)_{p\in\mathbb{N}}$ to $x\in E$.

Since $E$ is a finite dimensional normed space, all norms on this space are equivalents which means that the convergence is not altered by a change of norm (this is already explained in the comments I think)

I hope this is clear !